# Typescript - Validate with a list of alternations as text is entered in a text box

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I want to check for a valid mobile number as a user types it in
It should start with 04 followed by digits or 
should start with +61 followed by digits

But the validation should happen as the user types in and if the user is following the right sequence it shouldn't complain. Eg: A user could type just 0.. and it should still match but shouldn't as soon as any other digit other than '4' is entered next.

I am using the following regex, but the problem with this is it would validate '0', '04' as well as just '4'

^(0?4?)|(+?6?1?)

regexr.com/49bj4

Answer (score 1):

See https://regex101.com/r/seh5w4/4

```
^((04)|(0)|(\+61)|(\+6)|(\+))(?(2)(\d{0,6}))(?(3)((?(?=4)4\d{0,6})))(?(4)(\d{0,6}))(?(5)((?(?=1)1\d{0,6})))(?(6)((?(?=61)61\d{0,6})))$
```

---

```
^((04)|(0)|(\+61)|(\+6)|(\+))  does it start with one of these these

(?(2)(\d{0,6}))  if there is a group 2 (04) is it followed by 0-6 digits

(?(3)((?(?=4)4\d{0,6}))) if group 3 (0) is it followed by a 4, if so is that 4 followed by 0-6 digits

(?(4)(\d{0,6})) if group 4 (+61) is it followed by 0-6 digits

(?(5)((?(?=1)1\d{0,6}))) if group 5 (+6) is it followed by a 1, if so is that 1 followed by 0-6 digits

(?(6)((?(?=61)61\d{0,6}))) if group 6 (+), is it followed by 61, if so is that 61 followed by 0-6 digits
```

I used 6 digits, you should change that for whatever your maximum number of digits allowed after the 04 or +61.

I made it so it would not match if you used more than the maximum number of digits.

I believe it works as you type each character as you wanted.  (You didn't indicate allowing spaces between sets of numbers but this could probably be modified to handle that.)

Given the complexity of the regex I'm not sure I actually recommend using this approach...

Comment: switch (number.length) {
            case 0: {
                return true;
            }
            case 1: {
                return number.startsWith("0") || number.startsWith("+");
            }
            case 2: {
                return number.startsWith("04") || number.startsWith("+6");
            }
            case 3: {
                return number.startsWith("04") || number.startsWith("+61");
            }
            case 4:
            default: {
                return number.startsWith("04") || number.startsWith("+614");
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

the issue with you regex is the `?`

> Makes the preceding quantifier lazy, causing it to match as few characters as possible. By default, quantifiers are greedy, and will match as many characters as possible.

try this one `/^04\d+|\+61\d+/`:

`^` starts with `04` ( string ) followed by digits `\d+`, same for the other one.

```js
const a = /^04\d+|\+61\d+/g.test('+61938272')
const b = /^04\d+|\+61\d+/g.test('+71938272')
const c = /^04\d+|\+61\d+/g.test('04938272')
const d = /^04\d+|\+61\d+/g.test('+41938272')
const e = /^04\d+|\+61\d+/g.test('051938272')
const f = /^04\d+|\+61\d+/g.test('451938272')

console.log({a, b, c, d, e, f});
```

Comment: what happens with just +6 ? It should be valid as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 2 regexes for your use case.

One for validating while typing and another when you submit or focus out your input.

While typing: `^((04?)|(\+((61?)?)?)|(?!.))`

On submit: `^(04|\+61)[0-9]+`

Comment: One expression while typing doesn't work. You need an expression for all lengths upto atleast 4 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var patt = /^((0(4\d*)?)|(\+(6(1\d*)?)?)?)*$/ ;
```

```js
var patt = /^((0(4\d*)?)|(\+(6(1\d*)?)?)?)*$/ ;

console.log('0 ==>',patt.test('0') );
console.log('04 ==>',patt.test('04') );
console.log('4 ==>',patt.test('4') );

console.log('+6 ==>',patt.test('+6') );
console.log('067 ==>',patt.test('+67') );
```